# imported action not available in container

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to follow [piotrwitek's redux-typescript-guide.](https://piotrwitek.github.io/react-redux-typescript-guide/) when I'm writing redux actions for my view container.
For some reason, it stops because `setCarRegNr` is not found, even though it's imported.

Any idea why this fails?

```
import * as React from "react"
import { setCarRegNr } from "../actions/status"
type Actions = setCarRegNr
// ^ Cannot find name 'setCarRegNr'
```

**src/actions/status.ts**

```
import { createAction  } from "typesafe-actions"
import * as actionTypes from "../action-types/status"

export const setCarRegNr = createAction(actionTypes.SET_CAR_REG_NR,
  (carRegNr: string) => ({
    type: actionTypes.SET_CAR_REG_NR,
    payload: {
      carRegNr
    },
  })
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a constant as a type, you can get the constant's type using `typeof`:

```
type Actions = typeof setCarRegNr
```

Comment: Yeah, that was it. When I think about it, it _does_ make sense. :-P